# IndexError: list index out of range when using variabel to indexing

Tags: python

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    i = 0
    n = []
    t = int(0)
    b = int(1)
    while i < len(inputArray):
        noob = inputArray[t] * inputArray[b]
        t += 1
        b += 1
        i += 1
        n.append(noob)
    return n

print(adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]))
```

Can some one help me when I try to execute this its return

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sorry for my bad English Grammar

Comment: Trace the values. You'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your loop so that `i` only iterates up to `len(inputArray) - 1`.

Like this:

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    i = 0
    n = []
    t = 0
    b = 1
    while i < len(inputArray) - 1:
        noob = inputArray[t] * inputArray[b]
        t += 1
        b += 1
        i += 1
        n.append(noob)
    return n

print(adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]))
```

This is because your `noob` array is essentially just each adjacent pair of elements in `inputArray`. Naturally, the number of pairs in a `list` of `i` elements is `i - 1`. This means that you need to change your loop to stop one iteration before, as it's throwing the `IndexError` when `t` is the `len(inputArray) - 1` and `b` is the `len(inputArray)` (`b` isn't a valid value in the last iteration of your current code as there's not that many elements).

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful :)

Comment: @Flame25 No problem :) Please can you accept (and possibly upvote ;) ) this answer if it helped you? (as this will help those in the future who encounter your problem to know which solution worked for you)

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]
print([x*y for x,y in zip(l,l[1:])])
```

Here [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is used to create the adjacency pair

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here you set `i=0`, `t=0`, and `b=1`, thus your `b` always greater than `i` by 1. So, in the last loop (where `t` and `i` should equal `len(inputArray) -1`), the value of `b` should be `len(inputArray)` which is bigger than the length of your array.
I am not very sure about your excepted output, but I guess you could fix it like following:

```
while i < len(inputArray) - 1:
    noob = inputArray[t] * inputArray[b]
    t += 1
    b += 1
    i += 1
    n.append(noob)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `while` loop for a `for` loop and use `try / except` to return the result when it reaches the end of the iteration.  You can also add in extra `except` clauses to catch other errors and make use of `else` and `finally` if needs be .. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray):
    i = 0
    n = []
    t = int(0)
    b = int(1)
    for i in range(len(inputArray)):
        try:
            noob = inputArray[t] * inputArray[b]
            t += 1
            b += 1
            i += 1
            n.append(noob)

        except IndexError:
            return n
    return n

print(adjacentElementsProduct([3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]))
```